# Nativescript-Vue IOS Safe Area Layout Issue

Tags: ios, layout, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have an issue with the ios Safe Area with Nativescript-Vue on iPhone X and above.  I think it has something to do with the nested frames/pages setup we have.  We use a custom header and then for the 'body' of the app when we want to navigate we navigate pages within the nested frame.  The custom header will enter the safe area without an issue, but the bottom safe area remains.

The nested Page component itself appears to enter the safe area, but any layout inside that page appears constrained to be outside the safe area.

Here is a playground that shows what's happening: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=pXmqzC&v=3

In the playground you can see this by the borders I've drawn around the Page and the StackLayout.

Here's the layout code in case you can't access the playground sample:

```
<template>
    <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <GridLayout rows="90, *">
            <StackLayout row="1" height="100%">
                <Frame>
                    <Page actionBarHidden="true" height="100%" borderWidth="5" borderColor="red" >
                        <StackLayout height="100%" width="100%" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="green" borderWidth="5">
                            <Label text="Body" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Page>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
            <!-- Simulates a header -->
            <StackLayout row="0" height="90" width="100%" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" backgroundColor="blue">
                <Label text="Header" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" />
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you tried working with the [iosOverflowSafeArea property](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-5-ios-safe-area-support)?

Comment: @TomG yes, I've tried manually assigning it at all points up and down through the markup to try and see if it would help.  It did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix is to remove StackLayout above Frame.

```
<template>
  <Page actionBarHidden="true">
    <GridLayout rows="90, *">
      <!-- <StackLayout row="1" height="100%"> -->
      <Frame row="1" borderWidth="0">
        <Page actionBarHidden="true" height="100%" borderWidth="5" bordercolor="red">
          <StackLayout
            height="100%"
            width="100%"
            horizontalAlignment="center"
            verticalAlignment="center"
            backgroundColor="green"
            borderWidth="5"
          >
            <Label text="Body" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" />
          </StackLayout>
        </Page>
      </Frame>
      <!-- </StackLayout> -->
      <!-- Simulates a header -->
      <StackLayout
        row="0"
        height="90"
        width="100%"
        horizontalAlignment="center"
        verticalAlignment="center"
        backgroundColor="blue"
      >
        <Label text="Header" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center" />
      </StackLayout>
    </GridLayout>
  </Page>
</template>
```

Things to remember,

- You don't really need a StackLayout above Frame, it doesn't server any purpose right there.
- Avoid setting `height="100%"` by default content of Page / Frame takes it's whole height, you don't have to specify in percentage, at least when it's 100
- When you set verticalAlignment to center, you force the layout to fit to center on it's parent, but again why to set height to 100%, that doesn't make sense.